# In-app billing issue: "This version of the application is not configured for Billing through Google Play. Check the help center.."

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, apk, in-app-billing

I am using in-app billing in my android application. After signing, I uploaded a draft APK to the market (no debuggable in manifest), also included the com.android.vending.BILLING permission and all the files.I first tried the reserved android.test.purchased product ID for testing. It worked fine.

Now I add a 'In-app Product' with a new price for managed product to my app in the Google Play Develoiper Console and set the product to active. The APK is still in draft. I created a test user and reset my device to make that test user the primary account on my test device. Also mentioned the product id in String SKU in my main activity.(previously it was android.test.purchase)
Now, while trying to install the app, I am seeing this message:

"Error : This version of the application is not configured for Billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information."

I have waited for more than 2 hours and tried again. Still same. I have also checked the versioncode in the main application and in the phone's installed application is same. I am using In-app Managed Product. Also, I would like to add a product id with yearly subscription if managed product works fine. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting 12-24 hours. Sometimes it can take quite a while to kick in on Google's servers.